# What Is Wrong With Nvidia Quadro 3000M?

Tags: google-chrome, gpu, vlc-media-player, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

I have an HP laptop with the following specs:

```
Device:     Laptop
Brand:      HP
Model:      Mobile Workstation EliteBook 8760W

Processor:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2860QM CPU @ 2.50GHz   2.50 GHz
Memory:     Installed RAM   32.0 GB
GPU:        Nvidia Quadro 3000M 4GB
HDD:        2 TB 7500 RPM SATA

OS:
Edition:    Windows 10 Pro (64-bit)
Version:    21H2
OS build:   19044.2846
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0
```

Unfortunately, something is wrong with it. When I see videos coded with H.265, it works for a while before it suddenly crashes and powers off completely at once. This "while" could be an hour, a day, a week, or something around.

I use VLC 3.0.17.4 for now, but I used older versions before this one.

Another weird yet seems to be a related problem is that all of a sudden, the screen starts to have pinky squares, as in the attached picture, and the screen starts to have faulty windows drawings. This happens from time to time.

The two problems could or could not happen together.

I have to do a cold restart to get rid of it.

Usually, this starts when I browse on google chrome, but sometime I could be doing anything else.

**Is anyone had similar problems with this laptop model?
Is there a permanent solution?**

I looked in the internet for years with no luck.
I tried updating the drivers, especially the GPU driver, with no luck.
I tried updating the OS, VLC, Google Chrome, and so on, also With no luck.

I do not want to replace the GPU without being 100% sure it is the problem or at least it was someone else's problem with a similar case. Currently, I do not have a warranty.

[image]

Comment: Pink squares suggest your VRAM may be damaged

Comment: The crashes on video could be a power draw issue, battery failing to keep up - especially if it's as old as the rest of the computer. Last drivers seem to be 2018. The other issue is that the 'Sandy Bridge' generation of intel processors are not qualified for Win10 at all - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006105/processors.html

Comment: The 3000M is a [Fermi based GPU from 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#Quadro_(xxxxM)_series) likely it does not support h.265 decoding and so decoding is happening entirely on your CPU. This is likely an overheating or power supply issue.

Comment: Both previous comments are spot-on but IMHO @Mokubai 's nails it on the head.